# wordpress query making site very slow

Tags: post-meta, plugin-wpml

How can i improve this wordpress query that is making site very slow !

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) JOIN wp_icl_translations t 
ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id 
AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', wp_posts.post_type) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'post_views_count' )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
AND ( ( t.language_code = 'fr'
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post','page','attachment','grille','podcast','equipe' ) )
OR wp_posts.post_type NOT IN ('post','page','attachment','grille','podcast','equipe' ) )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: it is not the query that is slow, it is your DB structure. In any case hopefully you are using `wp_query` and not direct queries, in which case the question is not very answerable as it lacks enough context. Please edit the question, add all relevant context starting by defining "slow"

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id
WHERE 1=1 
AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', wp_posts.post_type) 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'post_views_count'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND (
    (t.language_code = 'fr' AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post','page','attachment','grille','podcast','equipe')) 
    OR
    wp_posts.post_type NOT IN ('post','page','attachment','grille','podcast','equipe')
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

JOIN with **wp_icl_translations** is changed to INNER JOIN, and one JOIN condition moved to WHERE block.

But, you need to make sure that **element_id** and **element_type** columns in the **wp_icl_translations** table are both indexed. If not, this query will be always slow.

**EDIT:**
But, the slowness comes from the ORDER BY where you are using a column that can't be indexed for ordering. Ordering by non-indexed column is very, very, very slow, and considering that you have a large database, if you continue to use ORDER BY as it is now, there is no way to optimize it because you have a complex query as is.

Comment: Hey Milan, thanks for the reply :) , i should've beenmore specific in my question, so sorry for that, here is the issue after debugging: I'm using newspaper 7 theme and i found out that in every single article "single.php" it calls many theme specified functions that results the query i mentioned above, and the problem is i don't need to fetch and verify in all of te post types in order to display a "single post" of post_type "post" (because my DB is too big) so it takes too much time to display a single post.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include few more remarks.